# Should a Scanner only be instantiated only once? if that's the case why so?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I know I'm going out on a limb here, but I just can't seem to understand why can't we just create an instance of the Scanner class twice. I'll add an example just in case.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Nope
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("What's your name?");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Welcome " + name + "!");
        scanner.close();
        
        // Now 
        System.out.println("where you do live?");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String country = sc.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("That's a lovely place");
        sc.close();
        
    }
}
```

And I get a runtime error which looks something like this

```
What's your name?
Kate
Welcome Kate!
Exception in thread "main" where you do live?
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at Nope.main(Nope.java:17)
```

I know it doesn't make sense to create a new object again of the same class, encouraging redundancy. But I just think it will clear my mind if I know why, don't you think so too?

What does the machine mean by **'java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found'** and people are saying Scanner ain't cloneable.

PS: I intentionally closed my first scanner and created a new object just to understand the issue.

Comment: Although I don't know of any application in which you would need 2 scanners at the same time, it does work.
The problem in Your example is, that You close the first scanner before using the second scanner. You need to *cascade* the second scanner. In particular, this means that all scanners must be closed in the reverse order in which they were created. To use the autoclosing mechanism is the safest way to do this. See the example down the page…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are actually two separate things going on here.

1. You should create one `Scanner` per input **source**.  For example, one `Scanner` for each distinct input file, one for `System.in`, one for each distinct socket input stream.

   The reason is (as Chrylis points out) is that various methods of `Scanner` read ahead on the scanner's input source.  When the characters are not *consumed* by the operation, they are not put back into the input source.  Rather they are buffered by the `Scanner` itself, and kept for the next `Scanner` operation to use.  So if you have two `Scanner` instances trying to read from the same input source, one may "steal" input intended for the other.

   This is the **real** reason why opening multiple `Scanner` objects on `System.in` is bad.  Not the "redundancy" argument that you proposed.  There is nothing fundamentally wrong with a bit of redundancy ... especially if it simplifies the application.  But scanners competing for input *may* result in unexpected behavior / bugs.
2. The second problem is that when you `close()` a `Scanner` that also closes the input source.

   In your case that means that you are closing `System.in`.  And then you are creating a second `Scanner` to read from the (now closed) `System.in`.

   When you attempt to us a `Scanner` to read from a closed `System.in`, that leads to a `NoSuchElementException`.

So if you hadn't called `close()` on the first `Scanner`, your code *might* have worked, but that would depend on the sequence of operations you made on the first `Scanner`.

---

> People are saying `Scanner` ain't cloneable.

They are correct.

Answer (score 4):

*This answer focuses on the **`close()`** operation and why there's no option to read again from ***`System.in`*** if a Scanner instance previously closed it, as the top answer already gave the correct info. Just if curious.*

---

> **[Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)**
>
> *When a Scanner is closed, it will close its input source if the source
> implements the Closeable interface.
> A Scanner is not safe for multithreaded use without external
> synchronization.*

- You should create a Scanner instance for each  source you want to read from.
- If you must share the same instance, you should implement the synchronization mechanism, as it's not thread safe.
- As other answers already pointed, `close()` is a "dangerous" operation.

---

### `System.in close()`

Let's suppose **`System.in`** was specified as source.

This is the close method from the [**`InputStreamReader`**](http://developer.claspath.org/doc/java/io/InputStreamReader-source.html)

```
public void close() throws IOException
{
    synchronized (lock)
    {
       // Makes sure all intermediate data is released by the decoder.
       if (decoder != null)
          decoder.reset();
       if (in != null)
          in.close();
       in = null;
       isDone = true;
       decoder = null;
     }
}
```

The variable that refers to **`System.in`** is the one called **`in`**.

**Two operations** are performed on this `InputStream` (*besides the null check*):

---

**1.** **`in.close()`**

[**This does nothing at all**](https://cdn.successconsciousness.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/being-lazy.jpg): [**`System.in`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) 's class (`InputStream`) just leaves an empty implementation of the inherited `close()` method (from *`Closeable`*)

```
/**
 * Closes this stream. Concrete implementations of this class should free
 * any resources during close. This implementation does nothing.
 *
 */
public void close() throws IOException {
    /* empty */
}
```

Not even the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#close()) *hide the truth*:

> The close method of InputStream **does nothing**.

---

**2.** **`in = null`**

This is the real reason why you won't be able to read again from **`System.in`**. Setting it to **null** unables any further read attempts from this source with a new **`Scanner`**.

---

***But... why does it throw a `NoSuchElementException` instead of a `NullPointerException`?***

The initialization of the `Scanner` **doesn't** fail in the step of creating its **`Reader`** instance. This is because the `InputStream` is wrapped into a new `BufferedInputStream`. So the `lock` Object is not null at the initialization of the Scanner's `Reader`:

```
public InputStreamReader(InputStream in) 
{
    super(in);  
    this.in = in;
    ...
}
```

.

```
protected Reader(Object lock) 
{
    if (lock == null) {    
        throw new NullPointerException();   
    }
    this.lock = lock;
}
```

You'll be able to create a second `Scanner` instance from `System.in` without any exception being thrown; As the `InputStream` is wrapped into a new `BufferedInputStream` instance, the `lock` Object is not null and passes the filter. But the inner `InputStream`, **`System.in`**, is null indeed, from the moment it was set to null in the previous `close()` operation:

[image]

This is the `lock` Object in the second initialization of the `Scanner` for `System.in`. The Scanner still doesn't know something will go badly, as its initialization was succesfull (*due to the wrapped `BufferedInputStream`*) and still believes its `InputStream` is valid.

But at the first try for reading again from `System.in`, this happens:

```
public String nextLine() {
    if (hasNextPattern == linePattern())
        return getCachedResult();
    clearCaches();

    String result = findWithinHorizon(linePattern, 0);
    if (result == null) /* result is null, as there's no source */
       throw new NoSuchElementException("No line found");

     (...)
 }
```

That's the moment where `Scanner` notices **at last** that *something is not going well*. The result of `findWithinHorizon` will return null as there's no source from where to find.

As a result of previously setting **`System.in`** to null in the `close()` operation, you get the error when trying to read from the second `Scanner` instance: **`NoSuchElementException`**.

Answer (score 3):

You should only create one `Scanner` *per input stream*. Among other things, the scanner reads ahead and so will consume more of the input than has actually been returned. (This is how it knows, for example, whether the input `hasNextInt()` and so on.)

It's entirely sensible to create multiple scanners if you have multiple input streams (such as processing multiple files), but `System.in` should only have a single scanner using it.

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner` *implements the* `AutoCloseable` *interface*
don't call `close` separately use instead the [autocloseable mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html)

```
public class Nope
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("What's your name?");
    try( Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in) ) {
      String name = scanner.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Welcome " + name + "!");

      // Now 
      System.out.println("where you do live?");
      try( Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) ) {
        String country = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("That's a lovely place");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

now everything works as expected and `close` is automatically called when exiting the try-with-resources block…

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple, You should only create one Scanner per input. The Scanner reads line one by one using nextLine() method. last check the condition hasNext() so you can find out the arguments.

**Try This**

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Nope{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What's your name?");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Welcome " + name + "!");
        // Now
        System.out.println("where you do live?");
        String country = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println(country +" Is a lovely place");
        if(!scanner.hasNext()){
        scanner.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**output like**

```
What's your name?
xyz
Welcome xyz!
where you do live?
rjk
rjk Is a lovely place
```